# Magento Different Transactional Emails Per Store View

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, multistore, email-templates, transactional-mail

I am looking to have different Transaction Emails per Store View (or even just per website).
In particular, I would like to have different Newsletter Subscription Success emails.

I have created a new Transaction Email Template, then I went to Configuration, and selected the Website / Site View in Current Configuration Scope. 
Then I went to `Customers -> Newsletter -> Subscription Options -> Success Email Template`, deselected "Use Default" and selected the new Template, and saved the config.

But despite doing all the above, the "Global" / Default Success Email Template is still being sent out for customers linked to that Site View.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

It should work as you described besides after all that you did you should flush the cache and then it should be fine.

I´ve just tested it on my staging environment and it worked fine as per follows:

```
System-->Transactional Emails-->Add New Template
```

Then choose to load the default Template `Newsletter Subscription Success`
After that you can do your adjustments and then go to

```
System-->Configuration
```

Then select your storeview and when you have done this please go to

```
Customers -> Newsletter -> Subscription Options -> Success Email Template
```

Then there you select your template you just created and that should work fine then.

Answer (score 3):

The success email template is send by `sendConfirmationSuccessEmail` method in `Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber` class:

```
// A lot code ...   
const XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_TEMPLATE       = 'newsletter/subscription/success_email_template';
const XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_IDENTITY       = 'newsletter/subscription/success_email_identity';

// A lot code ...   

/**
 * Sends out confirmation success email
 *
 * @return Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber
 */
public function sendConfirmationSuccessEmail()
{
    if ($this->getImportMode()) {
        return $this;
    }

    if(!Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_TEMPLATE)
       || !Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_IDENTITY)
    ) {
        return $this;
    }

    $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
    /* @var $translate Mage_Core_Model_Translate */
    $translate->setTranslateInline(false);

    $email = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');

    $email->sendTransactional(
        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_IDENTITY),
        $this->getEmail(),
        $this->getName(),
        array('subscriber'=>$this)
    );

    $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

    return $this;
}
```

As you can see is a system configuration used to define the template that will be used. You can set the template for each store using the store in scope `System -> Configuration -> Customer -> Newsletter`